# How to show notices with addSuccess() and addNotice() on Configurations page?

Tags: magento-1.9, configuration, adminnotification

I want to display success and error notification with  `Mage::getSingleton('core/session')->addSuccess()` and `->addError()` if the admin is on a specific Configuration Section.

The reason: I made an extension, which has a **separate section** in System / Configuration, and I want to give a feedback if it is configured properly or not, but **only when the admin is at that section**.

I tried to create a default.notifications block, which worked, but the  notification was a 'global notification', not a smaller notification box, which was located on the top of the settings fields of my extensions' settingfields.
Also: I want to add these notifications only if the admin is at this specific section's Configuration page.

Thanks!

Comment: Can you add an image indicating where exactly you intend to place this message? 'Separate section' in admin can have a few variations. An image will clarify any doubts

Comment: Is this what you want?                       
http://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/16634/magento-adminhtml-session-adderror-addsuccess-rendering-on-incorrect-pages

Comment: @ProxiBlue Yes, sure I'll upload the thing I want to get I have to prepare the pics.

Comment: @vinothavn yes, I can add those notifications, but my question is how to make those notices visible only on the System / Configurations page when my section is selected.

Comment: @ProxiBlue '[Screenshot](https://www.dropbox.com/s/lph16vv06euiu7b/notification.png?dl=0)

Sorry I got some problems sharing a screenshot :shame:

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The message area you are referring to

[image]

is populated from `Mage_Adminhtml_System_ConfigController::saveAction`.

Before the message is set, an event (`"admin_system_config_changed_section_{$section}`) is fired.

code ref:

```
Mage::dispatchEvent("admin_system_config_changed_section_{$section}",
                array('website' => $website, 'store' => $store)
            );
            $session->addSuccess(Mage::helper('adminhtml')->__('The configuration has been saved.'));
```

You just need to figure out what is in the section (`$section = $this->getRequest()->getParam('section');`) and you would most likely be able to target an event specific to your section saving.

There is also an alternative solution: Use a Hint field in the admin section.

Place a HINT group into your system.xml configuration file.
An example:

```
<hint>
   <frontend_model>dyncatprod/adminhtml_system_config_fieldset_hint</frontend_model>
     <sort_order>0</sort_order>
     <show_in_default>1</show_in_default>
     <show_in_website>1</show_in_website>
     <show_in_store>1</show_in_store>
</hint>
```

make sure it has the lowest sort order.

You will need to define the block class, below is an example, showing teh path as per the xml example.

[image]

It must contain a render method

```
/**
     * Render fieldset html
     *
     * @param  Varien_Data_Form_Element_Abstract $element
     *
     * @return string
     */
    public function render(Varien_Data_Form_Element_Abstract $element)
    {
        return $this->toHtml();
    }
```

You can then of course output whatever you need, and run whatever logic you need, via your block `adminhtml_system_config_fieldset_hint`

An example, to output some information about the installed extension:

[image]

Comment: Thanks, the Hint group will be the better, since I want to add some info there also. Thanks You for the great description!